# Docker not showing up as an option for Python interpreter on PyCharm

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have a dockerized project where the python interpreter sits in a container. When I work with PyCharm (macOS), it keeps on displaying a 'No Python interpreter configured for the project' message at the top. When I click on Add Interpreter, I get the categories on the left hand sideas follows:

- Virtualenv Environment
- Conda Environment
- System Interpreter
- Pipenv Environment

Seems like all tutorials assume that Docker will be in that list. I have the Docker plugin enabled in PyCharm. When I click on Build, Execution, Deployment -> Docker, I get the 'Connection Successful' message. I also have the Docker toolbar that I have set up with my docker compose file. It is aware that the images are up.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: What edition of PyCharm do you use?
Docker interpreter support is available only in PyCharm Professional.

Answer (score 5):

As per Sergey K.'s answer, the feature is only available in the paid version of PyCharm.